# TypeError when loading Excel spreadsheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to write data into existing excel file using Openpyxl, but I get a type error when loading the file.

Here is my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
DriverTableSheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1') 
DriverTableSheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value="value"
wb.save('file.xlsx')
```

And this is error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modify.py", line 11, in <module>
    wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 240, in load_workbook
    parser.assign_names()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.4.0b1-py3.4.egg\openpyxl\packaging\workbook.py", line 74, in assign_nam
es
    sheet = self.wb._sheets[defn.localSheetId]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType
```

Comment: TypeErrors giving NoneType like this are often caused by your input data. Check obvious things like the path of the excel file, the exact name of the sheet you are trying to load, and the cell index you are trying to inspect. You are probably pointing to a null somewhere. According to the trace, it looks like the second line is the issue. Therefore is the path correct.

Comment: Note you are using a beta version (the latest stable version is 2.3.5). Funny things happen with beta versions. Try using 2.3.5.

Comment: I think this has been fixed in the 2.4 branch. Can you please try using a checkout (http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#working-with-a-checkout) and submit a bug report if the problem persists?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have find out the problem, my excel file have complicated format, if i use a excel file with simple format, this code can run OK.